# hide price when price = 0

Tags: price

I need to show a message such as "call us" for certain products.

I cannot find any extension that works nicely with grouped products (which I use) - so making my own hack seems to be the only solution.

I saw this thread: [Hiding Price if 0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15982/hiding-price-if-0)

and using that, we get the code:

```
<?php if ($_product->getFinalPrice() == 0) : ?>
    <h2>Call  To Order</h2>
<?php else: ?> 
    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But maybe I don't put it in correctly, but it shows the call to order message for me + prices for all items in the list. Here is my code:

```
<td class="a-right">
                <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>

                <?php //new hide price function ?>
                <?php if ($_product->getFinalPrice() == 0) : ?>
                <h2>Call  To Order</h2>
                <?php else: ?> 
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php //end of new hide price function ?>


                <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml($_item) ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </td>
```

Any tips on how to get that working? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<td class="a-right">
            <?php if ($this->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>


            <?php //new hide price function ?>
            <?php if ($_item->getFinalPrice() == 0) : ?>
            <h2>Call  To Order</h2>
            <?php else: ?> 
            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php //end of new hide price function ?>


            <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml($_item) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
```

and if that dont work, change $_item for $_product.

Comment: OH YOU ARE A GENIUS!!! spent a day on this, and its fixed in 2 secs. LOVE YOU!!!!!