# Call for Price with the 0$ price

Tags: product, price, product-list

We have use this for our Call for Price:

[Hiding Price if 0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15982/hiding-price-if-0)

or

```
    <?php if ($_product->getFinalPrice() == 0) : ?>
                    <?php echo $this->__('Call for Price') ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

For list.phtml and view.phtml. It work fine, the only problem is the text call for price used to replace the price are not at the same place where the price is. Can anyone help us with this?

Here is a picture
[image: First with price, second without price and with text]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this is css question, should be asked in stack overflow.

But I will try to help you here:

You will need to add some `html` tags to your `Call for best price` text in order to apply your css.

Just wrap it with `<div>` or `<span>` exactly same as your `price` is wrapped and then give a class name as same as your "price" is given.

Remember, we are just trying to utilize the already written css.

This will do the trick for you.